# Modernizr converts all _self target links to _blank

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I am using Modernizr in my application and somehow it is converting the links from
`<a href="URL" target="_self">` to `<a href="URL" target="_blank">`.

I want to some links to open in the same window, even if they goes to different domain.

Below are the features for Modernizr I am using:

```
Build https://modernizr.com/download?-applicationcache-audio-backgroundsize-bgpositionxy-bgsizecover-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-boxsizing-canvas-canvastext-checked-cssanimations-csscolumns-cssgradients-csshyphens_softhyphens_softhyphensfind-cssreflections-cssscrollbar-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-ellipsis-flash-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-fontface-generatedcontent-geolocation-getusermedia-history-hsla-indexeddb-inlinesvg-input-inputtypes-lastchild-localizednumber-localstorage-matchmedia-microdata-multiplebgs-nthchild-opacity-placeholder-postmessage-rgba-sessionstorage-smil-supports-svg-svgasimg-svgclippaths-svgfilters-target-textshadow-video-webgl-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-domprefixes-hasevent-mq-prefixes-printshiv-setclasses-testallprops-testprop-teststyles-dontmin
```

If anyone knows which feature does that and how to customize or block it from doing so, please tell.

Comment: I thought Modernizr was just an API to check for functionality and doesn't modify any markup or css. I suspect your issue isn't related to Modernizr.

Comment: I thought the same, but my links render with `_self` targets when I don't load modernizr file on my webpage which makes me think that it is the culprit.

Comment: `Modernizr is a small piece of JavaScript code that automatically detects the availability of next-generation web technologies in your user's browsers.` Something else is happening, it is not Modernizr. Maybe somewhere in your scripts you are checking for functionality based on a call to Modernizr and toggling the _self and _blank

Comment: Ah! so it can be a dependency for somebody else to sneak in...

Comment: Not exactly. Someone could write something like `if (Modernizr.awesomeNewFeature) { toggleSelf(); }` and that could be changing your _blank to _self. Sounds like something to do with Mobile but i'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got what you are trying to explain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that `Modernizr` changes in entire DOM is the class attribute of HTML. So, whatever it is, it is not `Modernizr`.

It might be (and probably is) some bit of code that does this change depending of either HTML class being present/not present (`.property` or `.no-property`)

or `window.Modernizr` being present/not present or having object property `Modernizr.property === true | Modernizr.property === false`.